# how to control the time of an http post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post

I have a function that, according to the information stored in an array, sends it to the database.

I go through the array, and the information saved in each of the positions I send to the database, each with an http post

the problem is that, the time in which the information is sent with the http post are different, for example, the first position of the array is sent in 80ms, and the second in 20ms

therefore the information is not stored in the proper order. because first he got the number 2 before the number 1.

this is my code

```
$scope.sendlimits = function (){
var namelimit= document.getElementById('name').value;
var idmap= document.getElementById('map_id').value;

if($scope.numberofpoints==0 || $scope.numberofpoints==null || namelimit==null || namelimit==""){
    swal({
        title: "Error",
        text: "You must enter all the map data.",
        icon: "error"
    })
}else{
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.numberofpoints; i++){

        var latitudedb= $scope.arraycoordinates[i].lat;
        var longitudedb=  $scope.arraycoordinates[i].lng;
        var namelimitdb= namelimit+i;

        $http.post("/territoriosinteligentes/sendlimits", {name: namelimitdb, latitude: latitudedb,
            longitude: longitudbd, identificador: namelimit, map_id: idmap}).then(function(response)
        {

            $scope.status = response.status;
            $scope.data = response.data;
            swal({title: "Loading Limits",text: "Please Wait.",icon: "success"})

        },

        function(response) {
            $scope.data = response.data || 'Request failed';
            $scope.status = response.status;
            swal({
                title: "Error",
                text: "It was not possible to register the limits, you must enter all the data",
                icon: "error"
            })
        })
    }
}
```

}

this is an example of what happens[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want the end result to be? I don't really see why it's a problem that they are arriving out of order. You are replacing the $scope.data each time a response comes back. Is this really what you want or do you want to display all of the data from all of the responses?

Comment: what I am trying to do is that the information is sent in order to the database, but they are not sent that way because the upload times are different, and they do not have an order.